# issue with StackView Alignment

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, uistackview

I want to align 3 stacks with different alignment

1-Image 0-0 both edges as the image below

2- User info + text 10-10 form both edges

The Problem when I stack them together I can only set them all to 0 to all margins no stack per stack.

in my project all content stuck at left the image I want space in user + text stack from both margin !
How to fix this to appear like the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I really like `UIStackView`s, I used your problem as a reason to experiment. You can paste the following into an Xcode 7 playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let hostView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))
hostView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = hostView

let headerLabel = UILabel()
headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
headerLabel.text = "This is an info text shown on top of the image. The info text should inform the reader about the topic."

let topStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [headerLabel])

let image = UIImage(named: "header.jpg")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.backgroundColor = .yellowColor()
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

let bottomLabel = UILabel()
bottomLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomLabel.numberOfLines = 0
bottomLabel.text = "This is the story text. It is interessting and shows a lot insight to the topic. The reader should be eager to read it and at the end he/she would be able to share with friends and family."

let bottomStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [bottomLabel])

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topStackView, imageView, bottomStackView])
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.axis = .Vertical
stackView.spacing = 10

hostView.addSubview(stackView)

let views = ["stackView": stackView]
var layoutConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
layoutConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[stackView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
layoutConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[stackView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
layoutConstraints.append(headerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10))
layoutConstraints.append(headerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10))

let imageSize = image!.size
let imageHeight = hostView.frame.size.width * imageSize.height / imageSize.width
layoutConstraints.append(imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(imageHeight))

layoutConstraints.append(bottomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10))
layoutConstraints.append(bottomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10))

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(layoutConstraints)
```

Or you can have a look at the Story View page of my [UIStackViewPlayground](https://github.com/dasdom/UIStackViewPlayground/tree/master/UIStackView.playground/Pages/Story%20View.xcplaygroundpage).

Comment: thanks but this is a bit advance for me I mostly do it in the storyboard,do you think it is possible using storyboard ? I used the alignment in the attribute inspector but it isn't working

Comment: The trick is to use three stack views. On for the label on top, on for the label below the image and the main stack view. Then add trailing and leading constraints to the top and bottom labels in respect to the corresponding stack views.

Comment: So it won't break if i don't stack them all together Right?

Comment: The arranged view for the main stack view are the top stack view, the image view and the bottom stack view. The power of stack views comes from the ability to put stack views into stack views. You should watch the WWDC talk introducing stack views.

Comment: thank you bro ,it works very very well separately with only 3 stacks I hope it won't break later :)

Comment: it looks like programmaticaly more easy and controlled